# Number of red and blue marbles when probability of drawing two marbles of the same color is 0.5

Tags: probability

There are $n$ marbles in a container. The marble is either red or blue. The probability of you drawing two marbles of the same color on the first two draws is 0.5. What is the number of red and blue marbles?

Let $x, y$ denote the number of red and blue marbles, respectively. Then $x+y=n$ and

\begin{align}
    \frac{x}{n}\frac{x - 1}{n - 1} + \frac{y}{n}\frac{y - 1}{n - 1} = 0.5 \\
\end{align}

After some manipulation we end up with
$$
x^2 + y^2 - x - y - 2xy = 0
$$

1 equation. 2 unknowns, so there should be an infinite number of solutions. The issue is $x,y$ are constrained to be integers, so it's not as easy to find a solution. But after some plug and chug, I found that $x = 3$ leads to integer solutions for $y$, specifically $y \in \{1, 6\}$.

Is there a more procedural way to obtain $x$ and $y$? I don't want to resort to checking values for values of $x$ since that could take a long time.

Comment: So that's $(x-y)^2=x+y$.  Letting $z=x-y$ it's $z^2-z-2y=0$   Not so difficult.

Comment: @lulu. At this point do you just apply the quadratic formula and get $$z = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 8y}}{2}$$? And then it becomes much easier to find values for $y$ that result in an integer $z$?

Comment: No need.  We instantly get $y=\frac {z(z-1)}2$ which, since $x=y+z$ then gives us $x=\frac {z(z+1)}2$.  As those are both integers (when $z$ is), we are done.

Comment: @lulu, though note that (a) $z$ can be negative and (b) solutions where $x+y<2$ will not work when drawing two marbles without replacement

Comment: @Henry  Yes, you are correct.  This parametrization gives some unphysical solutions.  But all you need is $z>1$ to avoid those.

Comment: @lulu  If $z =-2$ then you get $x=1,y=3$, which is a satisfactory solution.  So only $|z|<2$ is unphysical

Comment: @Hennry.  Ah, that's true.